# Migration from Wordpress to Django?

Tags: django, wordpress

I created a website through WordPress, but now I want to migrate my site to Django without losing my data.

So, how can I switch my website from WordPress to Django?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be pretty easy. Once you've designed and built your Django app and it's functioning correctly, write a Python script that accesses all the necessary data form your WP database and creates the corresponding Django objects.

If you're not an experienced programmer this will be extremely hard, unfortunately. But you'll learn a lot.

Comment: How can i access data from WP database? can you share me any kind of links ?

Comment: It's probably running MySQL, so you can make a second option in Django's `DATABASES` in `settings.py`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/multi-db/

You should also be able to access it using any MySQL gui tools or from the command line.

Answer (score 2):

The database schema of the wordpress website may differ from the Django website that you have created. To migrate all the data from Wordpress to Django, you first need to export the page details in the XML file from the Wordpress `dashboard > Tool > Export` section.
After exporting the data XML file you can write a Python script that read from the XML file and populate the current Django database.

Answer (score 1):

The hardest thing is rewrite worpress template to django template engine. I dont see nothing else than manual facture

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).